# Local Mongo on Windows - couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed

Tags: windows, mongodb, windows-8, localhost, windows-8.1

Installed `Mongo 3.2` on `Windows 8.1`. Got this:

```
c:\foo>"c:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongo.exe"
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.5
connecting to: test
2016-04-26T13:41:31.032+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1
:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2016-04-26T13:41:31.034+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed

c:\foo>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
```

Why?

What else can I say?

Comment: Can you improve your question so that it becomes clear what you're asking?

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error this is how i solved it.
open your task manager
click on service tab
check for Mongo Db service
and right click restart it.
hopefully this will solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start the server process first.
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

First, you should install Mongodb as a service,

- Open your cmd as admin
- Run ( net start mongodb )
- Now you can run the command ( mongo ) and you will be able to connect normally, with no Problem.